# Getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: updateClock is not defined" error in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**`index.html is:`**

```
<html ng-app="clock"> 

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <h1 ng-controller="ClockController">{{clockTime}}</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

**`And app.js is:`**

```
var app = new angular.module('clock',[]);
(function(){

    app.controller('ClockController',function($scope){
        this.updateClock = function(){
            $scope.clockTime = new Date();
        };

        setInterval(function(){
            $scope.$apply(updateClock);
        },1000);
        this.updateClock();
    });

})();
```

When I visit `index.html` I keep getting following error after 1 second.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateClock is not defined

I have defined `updateClock` before `setInterval` is called still why am I getting this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your function `updateClock` is defined on the object `this`. When you are calling it inside the interval, JS engine cannot find the function definition for you. Change to:

```
app.controller('ClockController',function($scope) {
    function updateClock () {
        $scope.clockTime = new Date();
    };

    setInterval(function () {
        $scope.$apply(updateClock);
    }, 1000);

    updateClock();
});
```

---

By the way, use the service [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) instead of `setInterval`. In this way, you do not need to call `$apply` explicitly:

```
app.controller('ClockController', function($scope, $interval) {
    ...
    $interval(function() {
        updateClock();
    }, 1000);
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
this.updateClock = function(){
            $scope.clockTime = new Date();
        };
```

to

```
var updateClock = function(){
            $scope.clockTime = new Date();
        };
```

to have **updateClock** available in the scope of interval function. With **this** keyword you assign function to property of controller's function, however it doesn't make **updateClock** available as a variable.

Comment: What do you refer to as `parent function`?

Comment: It is controller's function

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to achieve what you want to achieve is by doing so:

```
angular.module('clock', [])
.controller('ClockController',function ($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.clockTime = new Date();

    var id = $interval(function () {
        $scope.clockTime = new Date();
    }, 1000);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $interval.cancel(id);
    });
});
```

**Don't forget to clean the interval on `$destroy` event**